# In Romans 3:22, why did Jerome prefer to use crēdunt rather than fīdunt?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, vulgata, word-choice

The Greek text of the Textus Receptus (1550) states,

> <sup>ΚΒʹ</sup> δικαιοσύνη δὲ θεοῦ διὰ **πίστεως** Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ εἰς πάντας καὶ ἐπὶ πάντας τοὺς **πιστεύοντας** οὐ γάρ ἐστιν διαστολή <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

which Jerome translated into Latin as,

> <sup>XXII</sup> iustitia autem Dei per **fidem** Iesu Christi super omnes qui **credunt** non enim est distinctio <sup>Vul</sup>

In English, it would be acceptable to translate διὰ πίστεως as “by [the] **faith** of” and τοὺς πιστεύοντας as “those who have **faith**,” thus emphasizing the similarity in the Greek stem πιστ-.

I noticed that Jerome translated πίστεως into Latin as *fidem*, from the lemma *fidēs*, but using a different root altogether, he translated τοὺς πιστεύοντας into Latin as *qui **credunt***.

Rather than *crēdunt* from the lemma *crēdō*, why didn’t Jerome instead use *fīdunt* from the lemma *fīdo*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All translation involves some form of (hopefully minimized) loss and (hopefully undistracting) gain.

In this case, though, the choice is clear, for a very simple reason: **[*fido*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfido) is not a good translation of [*πιστεύω*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpisteu%2Fw), when it simply means "believe."**

Greek *πιστεύω* has a range of meanings, including "trust," "believe," and "entrust": *credo* captures all of these meanings, while *fido* only captures a small part.

My (inexhaustive) look at a parallel text seems to show that the same Latin words were always used to translate these related "pist-" words from Greek:

- *πίστις* => fides
- *πιστός* => fidelis
- *πιστεύω* => credere

It is worth noting that *credere* was originally a financial term, and that a *creditum* was a "loan." Although it is the only appropriate translation for *πιστεύω*, it was necessary to hearken to *fides/elis* for the corresponding Greek terms

Jerome uses *confido* either to translate "θαρσεῖτε" (Jn 16:33) or "πείθεσθαί" (Rom 14:14), which unlike *πιστεύω* does not include the "believe" meaning.

Answer (score 10):

You can't really get into the mind of a particular author, and I do not believe Jerome ever commented on this point, but a couple notes should suffice. First, Jerome is writing for the common person, and it doesn't seem as if *fidere* is all that common a word. You can see for yourself how common *[credere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=credo&la=la#lexicon)* is compared to *[fidere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=fido&la=la#lexicon)*

It's not just this passage, it's most of the passages in the Vulgate.

Moreover, good translation practice both then and today did and does not adhere to the idea that related words must be translated using the same root. While Jerome is fairly literal much of the time, the Latin would be incomprehensible if it strictly translated "literally" the Greek/Hebrew.